# Excel VBA modules not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm using Excel 2010.

I added this code to my sheet and it works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1") > 0.5 Then
        MsgBox "Discount too high"
    End If
End Sub
```

But I want to create some way where I could create code and share that code across all excel workbooks on our network.

So I made a module and created an add-in and put the code INTO the module of the add-in.

[image]

I deleted the code from the sheet since I want the code to be accessible from the module.

I enabled the module.

[image]

And the VBA code doesn't work unless I put the code into the sheet. Please advise how I can just have this code in one file and have that code shared across all excel workbooks on our server.

Comment: To code worksheet events from an Addin you will need to code a Application Event Handler in the AddIn.  [See here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx0)

Comment: Take a look here http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment

Answer (score 0):

You must put the `Worksheet_Change` under the Sheetname of the Excel Objects. So if it is Sheet1 that you want this procedure to run on, you will have to put it under Sheet1. If you want it to work on all sheets in the workbook, you will need to put it under `ThisWorkbook` AND you need to change the procedure name to `Workbook_SheetChange`

Comment: That will only respond to sheet changes in the Addin sheets.  the OP wants to, quote _share that code across all excel workbooks on our network._